# Convergence and divergence of a series using limit comparison test

Tags: calculus, sequences-and-series, convergence-divergence

Given this series. $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}\frac{n!}{(2n)!}$ how can I solve this using Limit comparison test.

I can’t find the solution on how should I reduce the fraction and cancel out the $n!$  term.

Comment: Hint: Recall that $n!=1\cdot 2\cdot\ldots n$ and $(2n)!=\left(1\cdot 3\cdot 5\cdot\ldots (2n-1)\right)\cdot\left(2\cdot 4\cdot 6\cdot \ldots \cdot (2n)\right)$. Can you see something to cancel out?

Comment: I find this a weird question, as it is more natural to use the ratio test here.

Comment: You can do comparison with the series $\sum 1/n! = e$. However, this series converges by the ratio test, so perhaps it is rather circular. Although the ratio test is  nothing more but a convenient way to do comparison with geometric series, so perhaps not?

Answer (score 0):

If $a_n = \frac{n!}{(2n)!},\ $ then $\ a_{n+1} = \frac{1}{2(2n+1)} a_n,\ \implies\ a_{n} = \left( \frac{1}{2(2n+1)}\right)^n a_1 = \frac{1}{2}\left( \frac{1}{4n+2}\right)^n,\ $ as $\ a_1 = \frac{1}{2}.$

Let $b_n = \left(\frac{1}{4n}\right)^n.\ $ then $\ \frac{b_n}{a_n} \to 2e^{1/2} \in (0,\infty),\ $ and so by LCT, $\sum a_n$ converges $\iff$ $\sum b_n$ converges.

But clearly $b_n$ converges because $\ \frac{1}{4n}\leq \frac{1}{4}\ \forall n,\ $ and so $b_n\leq \left( \frac{1}{4}\right)^n\ \forall n,\ $ and so $\sum b_n$ converges because $b_n$ is bounded above by a decreasing geometric sequence.

The reason I find the question weird (or maybe it's just that my answer is weird?) is that my second paragraph where we use LCT was unnecessary here: we can instead go straight from my first paragraph to something similar to the third paragraph: " But clearly $a_n$ converges because $\  \frac{1}{4n+2}<\frac{1}{6}\ \forall n,\ $ and so $a_n\leq \left( \frac{1}{6}\right)^n\ \forall n,\ $ and so $\sum a_n$ converges because $a_n$ is bounded above by a decreasing geometric sequence. "

So my second paragraph was completely artificial and unnecessary, but there you go, I guess...